# Runtime 1004 error assistance required

Tags: excel, vba

What is the issue with the code below? I am receiving the runtime 1004 error.

```
Sub Save_CSV()
'
' Save_CSV Macro
'

'
        Columns("A:K").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Workbooks.Add
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone,     SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "G:\Business & Facility\Finance\Finance Documents\Payroll Journal\EH Payroll Journal IMPORT.csv" _
        , FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    Windows("EH Payroll Journal TEMPLATE Xero.xlsm").Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: It's unclear which line you're receiving the 1004 error. But, there are a few things apparent in your code that you can fix which will help you avoid that error and others... read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/9292/avoid-using-select-or-activate#t=201703070253108353635) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/11274/always-define-and-set-references-to-all-workbooks-and-sheets#t=201703070253108353635).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `ThisWorkbook` is "EH Payroll Journal TEMPLATE Xero.xlsm", then once you have done the `ThisWorkbook.SaveAs` you will no longer be able to activate the window containing it, because you have saved it as "EH Payroll Journal IMPORT.csv".

You are probably wanting to do a `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs` instead, to save the newly added workbook to which you copied data.